# Joomla 2.5, can´t put canvas element into article

Tags: joomla-2.5, articles, jce

Upon request I created a little HTML5 canvas animation for Christmas (so, tomorrow) and now I am trying to put it into an article. I am using JCE and turned off textfiltering in the configuration of Joomla itself and also in my editor profile. I even added canvas to the exceptions. When I copy my code to the article everything works fine, except that on toggle or save, it removes my canvas-element and replaces it with `&nbsp;`. JS and CSS stay and the `div` I use as a container for my canvas also stays.

JS fires until ALERT1.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
alert("ALERT1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
alert("ALERT2");
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to add your Javascript in the article which may not parse correctly, I would suggest using a 3rd party plugin to add it such as [Sourcerer](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer).

Once installed, you can add the following into your article:

```
{source}
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        alert("ALERT1");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        alert("ALERT2");
    </script>
{/source}
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use a free module called [Custom HTML Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-html-advanced) when I need to add custom code to Joomla. This module is similar to the built-in Custom HTML module, but with a couple of improvements:

> - No filtering (even for script tags);
> - Override module position chrome to remove unwanted wrapping HTML code around the module;
> - Add custom CSS code into HTML header for pages where the module is enabled.

Simply create a module with your code, publish it to a custom position (e.g. *MyCustomPosition*), and add the following text to your article wherever you want the module to be loaded (this can be done directly in the TinyMCE editor):

```
{loadposition MyCustomPosition}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JCE Editor

When you are editing the article, click on <kbd>Toggle Editor</kbd> once and add the code including `<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>`. Then do NOT click on <kbd>Toggle Editor</kbd> again; just click on <kbd>Save</kbd> button. The article will be saved without stripping the canvas tag.

[image: JCE Editor]

The result should be:

[image: Result]

**Note:** As user @johanpw mentioned, the code may be cleaned up next time you save the article. You'd have to keep a copy of the entire source code elsewhere.

## TinyMCE Editor

Go to "Extensions" -> "Plug-in Manager". Click on "Editor - TinyMCE". Inside "Basic Options" add `canvas[*]` to "Extended Valid Elements" field.

Now you can add `<canvas id="canvas">-</canvas>` to your article's html source.

Comment: I have used that first trick (saving from code view) sometimes, but it's not a good idea because if you ever need to change the article contents, the code is cleaned up next time you save. You'd have to keep a copy of the entire source code elsewhere.

Comment: @johanpw - Good point. I am going to edit my answer. I considered the special situations: small canvas tag and small period of time (Christmas).

Comment: Well, not toggling the editor basically did it, but now the script ignores my loop. I will try Sourcerer.

Comment: Sourcerer is overkill for this. If you are still having trouble just select none as your editor.